# Use one component for multiple routes with React router to render various data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having the following scenario:

I have 2 (in future maybe more) pre defined route path's: `my-route-one` and `my-route-two`.

I created 2 different components `MyRouteOne` and `MyRouteTwo` and configured the routes like:

```
<Route path={MyRouteOnePage} component={MyRouteOne} />
```

Works fine and expected behaviour.

Those pages are totally the same (styling, layout etc, except for some variables like:
`title, description, image`. Also per page I have to load a different script `config.MY_SCRIPT_ONE` and `config.MY_SCRIPT_TWO`.

I like to make one Component for this page and trigger the variables based on the various routes?

Do I have to store the variables in an array of objects like:

```
routeData: [
 {
  type: 
  title:
  script:
  // etc
 },
 {
  type: 
  title:
  script:
  // etc
 },
]
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render separate routes and explicitly pass props to each using the `Route` component's `render` function prop:

Example:

```
routeData = {
  routeOne: {
    type: 
    title:
    script:
    // etc
  },
  routeTwo: {
    type: 
    title:
    script:
    // etc
  },
}
```

...

```
...
<Route
  path={MyRouteOnePage}
  render={props => <MyRouteOne {...props} {...routeData.routeOne} />}
/>
<Route
  path={MyRouteTwoPage}
  render={props => <MyRouteOne {...props} {...routeData.routeTwo} />}
/>
...
```

To make this a bit more maintainable you could load up the component props along with the path into an array and map all the routes.

Example:

```
route = [
  {
    path: MyRouteOnePage,
    component: MyRouteOne,
    props: {
      type: 
      title:
      script:
      // etc
    },
  },
  {
    path: MyRouteTwoPage,
    component: MyRouteOne,
    props: {
      type: 
      title:
      script:
      // etc
    },
  },
  ...
];
```

...

```
routes.map(({ path, component: Component, ...props }) => (
  <Route
    key={path}
    path={path}
    render={(routeProps) => <Component {...routeProps} {...props} />}
  />
))
```

Or render a single dynamic route where the identity is incorporated in the route path, i.e. `"/route/routeOne"`.

Example:

```
<Route path="/route/:id" component={MyRoute} />
```

...

```
routeData = {
  routeOne: {
    type: 
    title:
    script:
    // etc
  },
  routeTwo: {
    type: 
    title:
    script:
    // etc
  },
}
```

...

```
const MyRoute = props => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const data = routeData[id]; // { type, title, script, ... } or undefined

  ...
};
```

Comment: @meez "Is there a better way to construct this helper and pass everything by one prop?" - That is effectively what I'm doing in my solutions above with `{...props}` of `render={(routeProps) => <Component {...routeProps} {...props} />}`. The only difference I see now is that you want to pass all the extra props into a prop named `"data"`, i.e. `render={(routeProps) => <Component {...routeProps} data={props} />}`, i.e. in the `Component` it'd be `props.data.title`, `props.data.description`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render` prop of Route instead of `component` and then you can simply pass props

```
<Route path={MyRouteOnePage} render={()=><MyRouteOne type="one" title="OnePage"/>} />
<Route path={MyRouteTwoPage} render={()=><MyRouteOne type="two" title="TwoPage"/>} />
```